# How long can be the value of "id" in notificationManager.notify()

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to pass unique value to `notificationManager.notify()`. The shortest way that's coming into my mind is `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

So i did following to get unique value.

```
 Long getCurrentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
 int id= Math.abs(getCurrentTime.intValue());

 notificationManager.notify("com.myapp.app",id , notification);
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns 13 digit `long` value.

I am little afraid about the length of this generated `id`.

I want to know that what is recommanded length of `id` in `notificationManager.notify()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a static counter in your main activity and you increment it before call **notify**

**Main Activity**

```
public static int NOTIFY_COUNTER_ID= 1;
```

**Notification class**

```
notificationManager.notify("com.myapp.app",++MainActivity.NOTIFY_COUNTER_ID, notification);
```

---

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in the comment, the app might be killed so you won't be able to access the static resource.

In order to avoid that you can use Shared preferences to save your incremental ID.

Or IMHO if you use Math.rand() with a big "gap" you should be fine.

Comment: but reference of static counter will be deleted once app process is killed, so there is always a change that the initial value of `NOTIFY_COUNTER_ID` may always be 1

Comment: Yeah I did not think about it actually, so I'd vote for using shared preferences instead of the static int. Even though I think if you use Math.rand between 1 and idk 9999 you should not have problems. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is too long to manage identifier.
Id is int, its 32 bit in java,
Recommended value will be -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647

Comment: If you are concerning of same value, i will suggest you to use SharedPreference  to store your identifier, and start with 1 and each time you can increment to it, it will solve your max number length issue